# How can I do this without using OMP TASK?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, task, openmp, threadpool

I have an array of 4 tasks called `array`. It is declared as following:
`type(tcb),dimension(4)::arrray`

with:

```
type:: tcb !> new type task control block  
     procedure(my_interface),NOPASS,pointer:: f_ptr => null() !< the function pointer
     type(variables)::variables !< the variables 
     integer :: state     !< the task state
end type tcb
```

I have only 2 threads to execute these 4 tasks. I want to avoid using `!$OMP TASK`.
When I used the tasking construct, I got something like this:

```
type(tcb),dimension(4),intent(inout)::array !< the array of tasks
integer,intent(in)::ff !< the counter 
type(tcb)::self !< self
type(variables),intent(inout)::var !< the variables
!OpenMP variables
integer::num_thread !< the rank of the thread
integer::nthreads !< the number of threads
integer:: OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM !< function to get the rank of the thread
integer::OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS !< function to get the number of threads    

!=======================================================================================================================================================
!$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(num_thread,nthreads,ff) &
!$OMP SHARED(array)
num_thread=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM() !< le rang du thread 
nthreads=OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS() !< le nombre de threads
       !$OMP MASTER
       do ff=1,3
             !$OMP TASK SHARED(array) IF ((num_thread .ne. 0) .and. (num_thread .ne. 1))
             call array(ff)%f_ptr(self,var)
             !$OMP END TASK
          end if
       end do
       !$OMP TASKWAIT 
       !$OMP END MASTER
```

Do you have any idea ? I want that when a thread finishes running a task, it moves directly to the next available task. It shouldn't wait for the other thread to finish.
How can I do it without using the OMP Tasking ?
I want to schedule the tasks alone not with the help of OpenMP. Is it possible ?

Comment: What you want is exactly how OpenMP tasking works.  Once a thread has completed a task, it will look for the next available task that is ready to execute. I do not see why you do not want to use OpenMP tasking then.  Can you please be more specific about what mean with "wait for the other thread to finish"?  The only way this happens in your code is that all threads have to wait until all threads are done at the end of the parallel region.  But that you cannot avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using OpenMP directives you have created a **serial program**. Here, I try to explain why. The task creation in your code is inside the MASTER region, in which the `num_thread` is **always zero**. From [specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmp.html):

> **Thread number**: A number that the OpenMP implementation assigns to an
> OpenMP thread. For  threads within the same team, **zero identifies
> the master thread** and consecutive numbers identify the other threads
> of this team.

Therefore the `((num_thread .ne. 0) .and. (num_thread .ne. 1))` expression is always false. Again from [specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmp.html):

> When an `if` clause is present on a task construct, and the `if`
> clause expression evaluates to false, an undeferred task is generated,
> and **the encountering thread must suspend the current task region, for
> which execution cannot be resumed until the generated task is
> completed**.

So, it means that you have a serial program. The master threads execution is suspend until a task is finished. Although it is not required (or specified) by the standard, in practice it means that your program will **run on the master thread only**, the other threads are just waiting. So, you have to remove the `if` clause and your program will be concurrent.

If you wish to run those tasks on 2 threads only, you have to use the `num_threads(2)` clause on parallel region to explicitly specify it.

EDIT: To answer your question, using tasks is a good choice, but if the number of tasks are known at compile time you can use sections as well

```
!$omp sections
  !$omp section
    ! first job is here
  !$omp section 
    ! second job is here
  ...
!$omp end sections
```

ps: you mentioned 4 tasks, but your code only generates 3 of them..
ps2: `end if` is not needed.

Comment: @hakim if this solves your problem, please accept the answer, so others can see that your issue is solved. On the other hand, if you need more info please tell us.